# What is the Flow return type of a React stateless functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typing, flowtype, static-typing

If I have something like this

```
const RandomComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent type={props.type} />
  </div>
)
```

how will I type annotate the return type with Flow, i.e., what should replace `/* ??? */` in the code below?

```
const RandomComponent = (props: { id: string, vino: number): /* ??? */ => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent veryImportantNumber={props.vino} />
  </div>
)
```

Edit: [This](https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#stateless-functional-components) is what the Flow docs has to say about stateless functional components. I may be blind, but I can't see anything about a return type there, only prop types.

Comment: Why would you like to specify a return type? It's a component, so wouldn't you always return its elements?

Comment: I'd like to do it because of consistency with other function declarations and because sometimes a component can return `null` or a component, but the question is really one of curosity, and I suppose it's really "what is the type of a JSX block/the return type of React.createElement?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return type of a pure component (which is the same type of the `render` function of a normal component) is `?React$Element<any>`.

As you can read in [its definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L116-L126) `React$Element` has a type parameter `Config` which is not very useful per se and it's there only for consistency with the definition of `ReactClass`.

So your definition can be written as

```
const RandomComponent = (props: { id: string, vino: number }): React$Element<any> => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent veryImportantNumber={props.vino} />
  </div>
)
```

or if you prefer

```
import type { Element } from 'react'

const RandomComponent = (props: { id: string, vino: number }): Element<any> => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent veryImportantNumber={props.vino} />
  </div>
)
```

or even

```
import React from 'react'

const RandomComponent = (props: { id: string, vino: number }): React.Element<any> => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent veryImportantNumber={props.vino} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Normally the `any` is supposed to be the internal component type. But if you are using a stateless functional component with arrow functions, this seems difficult to know what to use there?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's `React.Element`, which is a [polymorphic type](https://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#polymorphism-and-type-parameter-variance) (which I'm not 100% sure what it means), so the correct (enough) code would be

```
const RandomComponent = (props: { id: string, vino: number): React.Element<*> => (
  <div>
    <SomeSubComponent id={props.id} />
    <AnotherSubComponent veryImportantNumber={props.vino} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: please note that `React.Element` is not a valid type. The actual type you can use is `React$Element<*>`.

Comment: I found `React$Element` first, but then I looked through [flow's source code](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/e6f6386f1e0c775bd9795bb7ed43a22f555948d9/tests/react_modules/createclass-module.js#L9) and found that it's being used as `React.Element`. Any idea why?

Comment: Interesting. I guess you can use it if `React` is imported then

Comment: Added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your `.flowconfig`, setting `React$Element<any>` as the return type may throw the following error:

`error  Unexpected use of weak type "any"  flowtype/no-weak-types`

To avoid this, either pass no type at all:

```
type PropsType = { foo: string }

const Baz = (props: PropsType): React$Element =>
  <h1>Hello, { props.foo }</h1>
```

Or, pass a `props` type alias, instead of `any`:

```
type PropsType = { foo: string }

const Baz = (props: PropsType): React$Element<PropsType> =>
  <h1>Hello, { props.foo }</h1>
```